# To find unique characters in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

> Write a JavaScript program to find the unique characters in a string.
> The function uniqueCharacters must take a string as its argument and return the same after removing all the characters that appear more than once in the string. This is the main function.
>
> The function modifyString is the sub-function. This is invoked from within the function uniqueCharacters with the same string as the argument. This function will remove all the white space characters & convert the entire string to lower case and return the same to the caller.
>
> Note: You may verify the correctness of your function by invoking it from within console.log
>
> ```
> console.log(uniqueCharacters("Welcome to the Javascript course"));
> ```

Where am I going wrong? My code (below) isn't working correctly. The output should be: `welcomthjavsripu`.

```
function modifyString(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function uniqueCharacters(str)
{
   modifyString(str);
   var str1=str;
   var uniql= "";
   for(var x=0;x<str1.length;x++)
   {
       if(uniql.indexOf(str1.charAt(x))==-1)
       {
           if(str.charAt(x) === ' ')
           {
               continue;
           }
           uniql += str1[x];
       }
   }
   return uniql;
}
console.log(uniqueCharacters("Welcome to the Javascript course"));
```

Comment: **It looks like a typo-level error.** You're not using the return value of `modifyString`. You should have `str = modifyString(str);`, not just `modifyString(str)`. (There's also no point to the `str1` variable, although you could do `const str1 = modifyString(str);` if you want to avoid assigning to a parameter, which is sometimes frowned upon.)

Comment: Separately, if the output is really supposed to be as you've shown, you should make the entire string lower case, not just the first character (otherwise, you end up with `J`, not `j`, in your result).

Comment: (It would be nice if the people doing a JavaScript course knew the correct capitalization of JavaScript. Ah, well... :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your code:

- First you need to replace `modifyString(str)` with `str = modifyString(str)`
- Second you only call toLower on the first character of your string, but you expect your whole string to be lowercase. The `modifyString` function should simply be `return str.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Thanks :) but I'm getting an error as - expected : <welcome[to]java> but was: <welcome[ to ]java> Can you pls tell why so?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the test of the modifyString function expects it to remove whitespace, but you're doing it in the main function. In that case use `return str.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "")` in modifyString

Answer (score 0):

I would use the approach of counting characters with Map and then filter them.

```js
function uniqueCharacters(str)
{
   const uniqChar = new Map();
   const result = []
   for(const character of str) {
     if(uniqChar.has(character)) {
       uniqChar.set(character, uniqChar.get(uniqChar) + 1)
     } else {
       uniqChar.set(character,1)
     }
   }
   uniqChar.forEach((val,key) => {
      if(val === 1) result.push(key)
   })
   return result;
}
console.log(uniqueCharacters("AbaacddeR"));
```